# R: Is there a way to set the index back to 1 in a for loop if a condition is satisfied?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, indexing

I am looking to see if there is a way to reset a for loop if a condition is satisfied in R.

For example if I have a dummy dataset and parameters:

```
# repeatable random numbers
set.seed(999)

# half-hourly time vector
t=seq(0,365,1/48)

# s vec initalized to zero
s = rep_len(0,length(t))

# set parameters
s[1] = 9 # initial value
s_max = 10.0

d = 1.5-cos(2*pi*(t-8/48)) + rlnorm(length(t))

c = 1.9-cos(2*pi*t) + rlnorm(length(t))
```

I have a for loop that does what I want and creates an error whenever s[i] < 0 as such:

```
# time step
for (i in 1:(length(t)-1)) {
  if (s[i] < 0) {
    print("error: outage has occurred. Increase s_max")
    break
  }  
if (c[i] > d[i]) {
  if (s[i] < s_max) {
    s[i+1] = s[i] + (c[i]-d[i]) # s increases
    if (s[i+1] > s_max) {
      s[i+1] = s_max
    }
  } else {
      s[i+1] = s_max
   }
  } else {
    if (s[i] > 0) {
      s[i+1] = s[i] + (c[i]-d[i]) # s decreases
    } 
  }
}
```

However, if it fails I then have to increase s_max myself! So I was wondering if there was a way that I could set I back to 1 to start the loop again and increase s_max by 1.

```
if (s[i] < 0) {
    i = 1
    s_max = s_max + 1}
```

And so on..

But this does not seem to work! I was wondering if there is a way or function to call that could help with this.

This example should be replicable so feel free to try it out! Let me know if you have any troubles.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you set the value of `s_max` before you begin the loop? Can't you examine the values in `s` and deal with the case when a value is less than zero before you kick off the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't modify the index in a `for` loop.  You should use some other kind of loop.  For example,

```
for (i in 1:(length(t)-1)) {
  stuff
}
```

is the same as

```
i <- 0
while (i < (length(t) - 1)) {
  i <- i + 1
  stuff
}
```

except that you *are* allowed to modify `i` in the `while` loop.